# Why is my C program not asking for char choice

Tags: c

I am working on a C assignment for University. It will ask the user for a number and convert it to binary or octal. But all my code does is that it asks them for the number and then asks if they want it in binary or octal and then terminates. I want it so that they should be able to select binary or octal and then it will run the code. I will paste the code down below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){

    int mynumholder[100];
    int userinput;
    int i;
    char userchoice;

    printf("Enter the number that you want to be converted.");
    scanf("%d",&userinput);

    printf("Click B for binary and O for Octal");
    scanf(" %c",&userchoice);

    if (userchoice == "B"){

        for( i =0; userinput>0;i++){

            mynumholder[i] = userinput%2;
            userinput = userinput / 2;
        }

        printf("Now I will print the binary values");

        for(i =i-1; i >= 0;i--)
        {
            printf("%d",mynumholder[i]);
        }
    }else{
        if(userchoice == "O"){
            int o = 0;
            while(userinput > 0){
                mynumholder[o] = userinput%8;
                userinput = userinput / 8;
            }

            for(i = i - 1; i>= 0; i--){
                printf("%d\n", mynumholder[o]);
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Turn on higher warning levels. `userchoice == "B"` should be `userchoice == 'B'`. You need to learn the difference between chars and strings.

Comment: when i click `O` it terminates. Any idea why?

Comment: Did you change that to a char instead of a string as well?

Comment: yeah I did. But when i click `O` for octal it just terminates.

Comment: You should learn how to step through the program with a debugger.

Comment: You're not incrementing `o` after you assign to `mynumholder[o]`.

Comment: You can use the same algorithm for both octal and binary. Just set a variable to either `2` or `8` and use that as the divisor when you get the modulus and reduce `userInput`.

Comment: haven't resolved my original issue...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several problems:

1. You need to compare with `char`, not a string. `if (userChoice == 'B')`
2. You're not incrementing `o` in the `while` loop for the octal case.
3. The `for` loop in the octal case is using `i`, not `o`.

Here's the corrected code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){

    int mynumholder[100];
    int userinput;
    int i;
    char userchoice;

    printf("Enter the number that you want to be converted.");
    scanf("%d",&userinput);

    printf("Click B for binary and O for Octal");
    scanf(" %c",&userchoice);

    if (userchoice == 'B'){

        for( i =0; userinput>0;i++){

            mynumholder[i] = userinput%2;
            userinput = userinput / 2;
        }

        printf("Now I will print the binary values");

        for(i =i-1; i >= 0;i--)
        {
            printf("%d",mynumholder[i]);
        }
    }else{
        if(userchoice == 'O'){
            int o = 0;
            while(userinput > 0){
                mynumholder[o++] = userinput%8;
                userinput = userinput / 8;
            }

            for(o = o - 1; o>= 0; o--){
                printf("%d\n", mynumholder[o]);
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Got it. You are a life saver!

Answer (score 0):

## Double quotes ("") for string, single quotes ('') for chars...

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    int main(){

    int mynumholder[100], userinput, i;
    char userchoice;

    printf("Enter the number that you want to be converted: ");
    scanf("%d",&userinput);

    printf("Press B for binary and O for Octal: ");
    scanf(" %c",&userchoice);

    if (userchoice == 'B' || userchoice == 'b') 
    {
         for(i = 0; userinput > 0; ++i)
         {
             mynumholder[i] = userinput%2;
             userinput = userinput / 2;
          }

          printf("Now I will print the binary values: ");

          for(i = i - 1; i >= 0; --i) printf("%d", mynumholder[i]);
    }
    else
    {
        if(userchoice == 'O' || userchoice == 'o')
        {
            int o = 0;
            while(userinput > 0)
            {
                mynumholder[o] = userinput%8;
                userinput = userinput / 8;
            }

            for(i = i - 1; i>= 0; i--) printf("%d\n", mynumholder[o]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
    }
```